# Maven child profile activated on parent profile property

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles, parent-pom

I have two pom's an aggregate and a child, the child has a profile I would like to be activated based upon a property set in the parents profile eg.

parent pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>emptyModules</id>

        <modules>
            <module>child</module>
        </modules>

        <properties>
            <emptyModules>true</emptyModules>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The child has two profiles one with some modules the other without

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>modules</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <modules>
            <module>module1</module>
            <module>module2</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>emptyModules</id>

        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>emptyModules</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I activate the parent emptyModules profile I want the child emptyModule profile to activate, however the default profile is used instead! Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because profile activation happens at the very beginning of the build process. If I understand it correctly, it is done before any part of the pom is executed.

Comment: What Maven command are you using when you "activate" the parent emptyModules profile?

Comment: eg. `mvn clean install -PemptyModules`

Comment: Never add/remove modules by profiles...[otherwise this will lead to problems](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/)...The question is why do you need this? What kind of problem are you trying to solve...

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, I made a small example of what you had and it worked for me `mvn clean install -P emptyModules` did only build the parent and the child without any submodules and `mvn clean install` was building everything. If you're interested in the code, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate profiles based on properties:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>someprop</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This could be used to activate a parent and child profile at once.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I have above in the child pom profile

Comment: Sorry, I did not read thorough enough. It don't think it is possible to do in your way, but you could set parameters on the command line and use in different profiles.